# How to define an objective function with multiplication of 2-d matrices in Gurobipy

Tags: python, gurobi

I am trying to set as an objective function a product of 4 matrices.

In mathematical terms, my objective function looks as this:

[image]

where u is a unit vector of length n, D is a matrix mxn, C is a matrix nxn and delta is a variable of length 3.

I defined it as:

```
D = np.array([[50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 100, 10, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 80, 100]])
c = np.array([10, 4, 9, 5, 6, 8])
C = np.diag(c)

m = gp.Model("relaxation")
delta = m.addMVar(shape=(6,1), lb=0.0, ub=1.0, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='delta')
m.setObjective(u@(D @ C @ delta))
```

But I get this error which states `gurobipy.GurobiError: Variable is not a 1D MVar object`, my question is how do I define it properly, also a place where I can find a suitable example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues here:

1. u must be a vector of length **m**
2. delta should be a *vector* of length **n**

Here is some corrected code:

```
import numpy as np
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB

D = np.array([[50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 100, 10, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 80, 100]])
c = np.array([10, 4, 9, 5, 6, 8])
C = np.diag(c)
u = np.ones(3)

m = gp.Model("relaxation")
delta = m.addMVar(6, lb=0.0, ub=1.0, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='delta')
m.setObjective(u @ D @ C @ delta)
```

Answer (score 1):

<del>The `m.setObjective()` method can only be used for `Var` objects.</del> Since you're using `MVar`s, you can set the objective using matrix semantics by means of [`m.setMObjective()`](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/py_model_setmobjective.html) like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import gurobipy as gp

u = np.ones(3)
D = np.array([[50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 100, 10, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 80, 100]])
c = np.array([10, 4, 9, 5, 6, 8])
C = np.diag(c)

m = gp.Model("relaxation")
delta = m.addMVar(shape=(6,), lb=0.0, ub=1.0, vtype="C", name='delta')
m.setMObjective(None, u @ D @ C, 0.0, xc=delta)
```

Note also that `delta` should have shape `(6,)`, not `(6,1)`.